# How to use attributes to specify that System.DateTime should be smalldatetime in SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, public

Is it possible to use C# attributes to specify that a `System.DateTime` in my model should use the SQL `smalldatetime` type?

```
[DataType(????)]
public DateTime somedate { get; set; }
....
```

Comment: You didn't try the `DataTypeAttribute` constructor accepting a string?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an auto generated Model by EF? If Yes, you can try with Code first approach